# variable range using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, nested, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function from a angularjs controller.

injection part:

```
var $scope, $controller;

beforeEach(module('sigfoxSDISApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$log_, _$translate_, _DeviceService_, _$filter_, _translatableIndexFilter_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller =  $controller('AcquitModalCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        $log: _$log_,
        $translate: _$translate_,
        DeviceService: _DeviceService_,
        $filter_: _$filter_,
        translatableIndexFilter: _translatableIndexFilter_
    });
}));
```

tests:

```
describe('$scope.getReport', function(){
    this.success = 0;
    this.errors = 0;
    
    it('returns an object with a type, a title and a report', function(){
        var result = $scope.getReport(this.success, this.errors);
        expect(result.type).toBeDefined();
        expect(result.title).toBeDefined();
        expect(result.report).toBeDefined();
    });
    
    describe('getting type, report and title when success = 0 and errors = 1', function(){
        this.errors = 1;
        var result = $scope.getReport(this.success, this.errors);
        
        it('returns a type error', function(){
            expect(result.type).toEqual('error');
        });
        
        it('returns a report empty string', function(){
           expect(result.report).toEqual(''); 
        });
        
        it('returns a title which is not empty string', function(){
            expect(result.title).toMatch(/[a-z]/);
        });
    });
});
```

The first 'it' function works fine.
In the 'getting type, report and title when success = 0 and errors = 1', i get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReport' of undefined"

So $scope is no more defined after the first 'it' function. I don't understand why.

From the [Jasmine Doc](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

> Nesting describe Blocks
>
> Calls to describe can be nested, with specs defined at any level. This allows a suite to be composed as a tree of functions. Before a spec is executed, Jasmine walks down the tree executing each beforeEach function in order. After the spec is executed, Jasmine walks through the afterEach functions similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add beforeEach in each describe to change the variables values and execute the getReport function like this:

```
describe('$scope.getReport', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.success = 0;
    this.errors = 0;
  });


  it('returns an object with a type, a title and a report', function(){
    var result = $scope.getReport(this.success, this.errors);
    expect(result.type).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.title).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.report).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getting type, report and title when success = 0 and errors = 1', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      this.errors = 1;
      this.result = $scope.getReport(this.success, this.errors);
    )}

    it('returns a type error', function(){
        expect(this.result.type).toEqual('error');
    });

    it('returns a report empty string', function(){
       expect(this.result.report).toEqual(''); 
    });

    it('returns a title which is not empty string', function(){
        expect(this.result.title).toMatch(/[a-z]/);
    });
});
```

});